# Combining results with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a loop that outputs some data. Each loop adds a header and footer to the output content.

```
<div class="box" data-res="4">
    <div class="header">header 4</div>
    <div class="content">content 4a</div>
    <div class="footer">footer 4</div>
</div>

<div class="box" data-res="4">
    <div class="header">header 4</div>
    <div class="content">content 4b</div>
    <div class="footer">footer 4</div>
</div>

<div class="box" data-res="4">
    <div class="header">header 4</div>
    <div class="content">content 4c</div>
    <div class="footer">footer 4</div>
</div>

<div class="box" data-res="5">
    <div class="header">header 5</div>
    <div class="content">content 5</div>
    <div class="footer">footer 5</div>
</div>

<div class="box" data-res="6">
    <div class="header">header 6</div>
    <div class="content">content 6</div>
    <div class="footer">footer 6</div>
</div>
```

I would like to combine the content of the blocks that have the same data attribute value and have a single header and footer. The final output should look like:

```
header 4
content 4a
content 4b
content 4c
footer 4

header 5
content 5
footer 5

header 6
content 6
footer 6
```

Can't seem to be able to wrap my mind around this. 
Here's my [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/f3jxLz14/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo in your script. The variable is created as `res`, but you use it on the next line as `rid`. After you fix that, the code works.

The error message can be found in the JavaScript console (F12) by the way. It works within jsFiddle too. :)

```js
$('.box').each(function () {
    var res = $(this).attr('data-res'),
        box = $('.box[data-res="' + res /* <- there */ + '"]');

    
    if (box.length > 1) {
        $(box).find('.header').not(':first').remove();
        $(box).find('.footer').not(':last').remove();
    }
});
```

```css
.box {
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box" data-res="4">
    <div class="header">header 4</div>
    <div class="content">content 4a</div>
    <div class="footer">footer 4</div>
</div>
<div class="box" data-res="4">
    <div class="header">header 4</div>
    <div class="content">content 4b</div>
    <div class="footer">footer 4</div>
</div>
<div class="box" data-res="4">
    <div class="header">header 4</div>
    <div class="content">content 4c</div>
    <div class="footer">footer 4</div>
</div>
<div class="box" data-res="5">
    <div class="header">header 5</div>
    <div class="content">content 5</div>
    <div class="footer">footer 5</div>
</div>
<div class="box" data-res="6">
    <div class="header">header 6</div>
    <div class="content">content 6</div>
    <div class="footer">footer 6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh, thanks. Long day!..

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.appendTo()` to append `.content` of `.box` having same `data-res` as current element, `.not(":has(.content)")` to select `.box` where `.content` removed , `.detach()`

```
$('.box').each(function () {
    if ($(".box").not(this).data("res") === $(this).data("res")) {
      $(".box[data-res="+$(this).data("res")+"]").not(this)
      .find(".content")
      .appendTo(
        $(".content:last", this)
      );
      $(".box[data-res="+$(this).data("res")+"]")
      .not(":has(.content)")
      .detach()
    }
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/f3jxLz14/3/

Answer (score 0):

I assumed that you wanted to combine boxes, also.

```
function combineBoxes() {
    $('.box').each(function () {
        var thisBox = $(this);
        var thisRes = $(this).attr('data-res');
        var nextBox = $(this).next('.box');
        var nextRes = nextBox.attr('data-res');

        if (nextRes === thisRes) {
            var nextHtml = nextBox.find('.content');
            nextHtml.insertBefore(thisBox.find('.footer'));

            nextBox.remove();

            combineBoxes();
        }
    });
}

combineBoxes();
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/f3jxLz14/2/)**